# Array lookup value from dynamic string

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic

I'm trying to build a dynamic associative array value lookup function (within a class):

```
class Family
{
    public static $members = array(
        'one' => array(
            'child' => 0,
            'children' => 5
            ),
        'two' => array(
            'child' => 2,
            'children' => null
            )
    );

    public static function resolveMemberValue()
    {
        $chain = func_get_args();
        $lookup = 'members' . '[\'' . implode('\'][\'', $chain) . '\']';

        var_dump( $lookup );

        return static::$$lookup;
    }
}

Family::resolveMemberValue('one', 'child');
```

But this results in:

> string(23) "members['one']['child']"
>   Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: Family::$members['one']['child'] in /family.php on line 23
>   PHP Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: Family::$members['one']['child'] in /family.php on line 23

Though, copying the dumped value, and pasting inside the script + appending dollar sign, it returns what's expected:

```
var_dump( Family::$members['one']['child'] );
```

> int(0)

Reason why I need this is, because it will be used with multiple variables, and called from generator functions.

What is wrong with the snippet?

Comment: This class returns `Parse error: syntax error, ` you can not declear array like that in PHP ???  See : http://codepad.viper-7.com/BP00wP

Comment: Woops, yes, didn't copy paste the whole code, rewrote only the needed parts, the `function` keyword slipped into the void.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, had to just tinker a little - managed to make a helper function.

The function replaces the `implode()` and the explicit key definition.

```
function array_lookup()
{
    $chain = func_get_args();
    $array = array_shift($chain);

    foreach ($chain as $key) $array = $array[$key];

    return $array;
}

$test = array(
    'one' => array(
        'child' => 0,
        'children' => 5
        ),
    'two' => array(
        'child' => 2,
        'children' => null
        )
    );

var_dump($test, 'one', 'child'); // int(0)
```

I have left out any kind of error checking for this example, but it does what I was looking for.

And yes, for my example, [it nails it](http://codepad.viper-7.com/6pqY1v).

Answer (score 0):

Variable variables only substitutes in a string for the name of the variable.   It can't evaluate the content of that string (in this case the string `members['one']['child']`)

Your code is looking for a static property literally with the named `$members['one']['child']` not an element of the static array `$members`.

Try this instead:

```
$member = static::$members[$chain[0]];
return $member[$chain[1]];
```

Also, I'd recommend not using `func_get_args()`, but explicitly naming your parameters in the method declaration.  Some features of PHP a best left behind....

Comment: I think seeing `func_get_args()` is better than seeing `func(array('foo', 'bar', 'baz'))` everywhere.

Comment: @RobertK not suggesting passing arbitrary arrays as the only argument, but clear parameters like:  func($fname, $lname, $age);

Comment: I agree with that. However, in his example each argument is yet another child within the array.